# Add a custom button in column header dropdown menus {EXTJS 4}

Tags: extjs4

I want a button in column header dropdown menu of grid in extjs4.
so that i can add or delete columns which are linked in database.
[image: The button in red area is the one i'm looking for...]

Any help will be appreciated...
Thankyou..:)

Comment: Hiding/showing columns is already implemented in the Columns submenu. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sir, i'm trying to put a custom button like this button named as "Add New Column" Which will open a window to add new column in database.....

Comment: Adding columns at will might be over complicated. Why don't you add them all originally and mark some of them is hidden? This way user can just check/uncheck them using standard interface

Comment: Sir, i understand the risk....i have around 13 columns out of which 5 are displayed and rest are already hidden, The company owner wants to create new columns on his own will. Its something like excel kind of operation on extjs grids..:)

Comment: You're screwed then :) As far as I know there is no standard way of doing so. You will need to go deep to the ExtJs code, figure out where and how they create this menu and add custom your logic there.

Comment: hahahaha...no problem sir.....Seriously thanks for the effort.....I really appreciate that.:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couple of months ago I had the same problem. I've managed to solve it by extending [Ext.grid.header.Container](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container) (I've overrided [getMenuItems](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-method-getMenuItems) method). However, recently, I've found another solution which requires less coding: just add menu item manualy after grid widget is created.

I'll post the second solution here:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // ...
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            var menu = this.headerCt.getMenu();
            menu.add([{
                text: 'Custom Item',
                handler: function() {
                    var columnDataIndex = menu.activeHeader.dataIndex;
                    alert('custom item for column "'+columnDataIndex+'" was pressed');
                }
            }]);           
        }
    }
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/hDpuT/).​

#### UPDATE

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hDpuT/4/) for ExtJs4.1.

Comment: yes i did saw the demo and its working perfectly......But when i applied to my grid, i'm getting this error called "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getMenu' of undefined" ...Do i need to include a plugin or something.....

Comment: @NarayaN, in my case `this == grid`. In your case `this == something-else`. You should replace `this` with reference to the grid. One possible way is to create grid, assign it to some variable. And then perform all manipulations using this variable (like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/hDpuT/2/)). The point is you have to be able to access reference to the grid.

Comment: Yes you are correct sir. The thing is i'm using bryntum charts which has grid on left and chart view on right side. I was using the listeners for whole application which is wrong. I will sort out the remaining thing. But thank you very much. I am kindfull to you for your precious time...Thnaks...:)

Comment: @george, it does. Updated my answer (when you switch to another version of extjs you have to include corresponding css as well).

Comment: @MolecularMan, oh, I have found that if you use the metadata response with `listeners:{metachange:function(store,meta){if (!this.meta){this.meta=meta;grid.reconfigure(store,meta.columns);}}` under the store then your method won't work. The columns under the grid needs to be specified statically, metaData response makes it not working.

Comment: It worked after I've put your code within the `metachange`. Thank you. Basically now getMenu() works after the columns are created by metaData.

Comment: @MolecularMan This method looks great, I notice that this menu is added to all column, how do you apply this new item to just one column?

Comment: If the order columns is changed (by drag-drop) this additional menu item is no longer there. The header menu is re-created in this case. The menu items should be added in the 'menucreate' handler, as suggested by @chemoish

Answer (score 9):

From what I have been seeing, you should avoid the afterrender event.

Context:

The application I am building uses a store with a dynamic model.  I want my grid to have a customizable model that is fetched from the server (So I can have customizable columns for my customizable grid).

Since the header wasn't available to be modified (since the store gets reloaded and destroys the existing menu that I modified - using the example above). An alternate solution that has the same effect can be executed as such:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // ...

    initComponent: function () {
        // renders the header and header menu
        this.callParent(arguments);

        // now you have access to the header - set an event on the header itself
        this.headerCt.on('menucreate', function (cmp, menu, eOpts) {
            this.createHeaderMenu(menu);
        }, this);
    },

    createHeaderMenu: function (menu) {
        menu.removeAll();

        menu.add([
            // { custom item here }
            // { custom item here }
            // { custom item here }
            // { custom item here }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @NarayaN Yup, I have quickly found that it can take hours to find the "proper" solution to most ExtJS4 issues.  Sometimes I even have to modify the core files.  But don't give up by settling for the quick and dirty!

Comment: Sometimes ExtJS won't meet you halfway and you do have to do quick and dirty :) I couldn't get this.headerCt to work on my custom grid class so I ended up using `this.down('headercontainer');`

Comment: Correction, if you are using a lockable a grid, there are two headerCts that can be reached using `this.lockedGrid.headerCt` or `this.normalGrid.headerCt`, `this` in this case is the grid object.

Comment: In addition, I'd note that you can respond to this event from within a controller, which may be more appropriate for your code organization depending on how dynamic the custom menu items are, using the ComponentQuery `"grid headercontainer"`. [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-event-menucreate)

Answer (score 4):

For people who would like to have not just one "standard" column menu but have an individual columnwise like me, may use the following

```
initComponent: function ()
{
    // renders the header and header menu
    this.callParent(arguments);

    // now you have access to the header - set an event on the header itself
    this.headerCt.on('menucreate', function (cmp, menu, eOpts) {
        menu.on('beforeshow', this.showHeaderMenu);
    }, this);
},

showHeaderMenu: function (menu, eOpts)
{
    //define array to store added compoents in
    if(this.myAddedComponents === undefined)
    {
        this.myAddedComponents = new Array();
    }

    var columnDataIndex = menu.activeHeader.dataIndex,
        customMenuComponents = this.myAddedComponents.length;

    //remove components if any added
    if(customMenuComponents > 0)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < customMenuComponents; i++)
        {
            menu.remove(this.myAddedComponents[i][0].getItemId());
        }

        this.myAddedComponents.splice(0, customMenuComponents);
    }

    //add components by column index
    switch(columnDataIndex)
    {
        case 'xyz': this.myAddedComponents.push(menu.add([{
                            text: 'Custom Item'}]));

                break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I took @nobbler's  answer an created a plugin for this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.CustomGridColumnMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    init: function (component) {
        var me = this;

        me.customMenuItemsCache = [];

        component.headerCt.on('menucreate', function (cmp, menu) {
            menu.on('beforeshow', me.showHeaderMenu, me);
        }, me);
    },

    showHeaderMenu: function (menu) {
        var me = this;

        me.removeCustomMenuItems(menu);
        me.addCustomMenuitems(menu);
    },

    removeCustomMenuItems: function (menu) {
        var me = this,
            menuItem;

        while (menuItem = me.customMenuItemsCache.pop()) {
            menu.remove(menuItem.getItemId(), false);
        }
    },

    addCustomMenuitems: function (menu) {
        var me = this,
            renderedItems;

        var menuItems = menu.activeHeader.customMenu || [];

        if (menuItems.length > 0) {
            if (menu.activeHeader.renderedCustomMenuItems === undefined) {
                renderedItems = menu.add(menuItems);
                menu.activeHeader.renderedCustomMenuItems = renderedItems;
            } else {
                renderedItems = menu.activeHeader.renderedCustomMenuItems;
                menu.add(renderedItems);
            }
            Ext.each(renderedItems, function (renderedMenuItem) {
                me.customMenuItemsCache.push(renderedMenuItem);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is the way you use it (customMenu in the column config let you define your menu):

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    plugins: ['Ext.grid.CustomGridColumnMenu'],
    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'name',
            customMenu: [
                {
                    text: 'My menu item',
                    menu: [
                        {
                            text: 'My submenu item'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

The way this plugin works also solves an issue, that the other implementations ran into. Since the custom menu items are created only once for each column (caching of the already rendered version) it will not forget if it was checked before or not.