# Renaming column header from column menu in Ext JS 4.1

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

[image]

Is it possible add an item to this menu in order to rename the column header?

Answer (score 2):

The question seems kind of vague and I believe the image attached is throwing me off.

Customizing a grid header menu ([Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348581/add-a-custom-button-in-column-header-dropdown-menus-extjs-4/11659872#11659872))..

See either answer.

My final product I have even customized my answer further:

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.headerCt.on('headerclick', function (header, column, event, html) {
        if (column.xtype == 'rownumberer') {
            return false;
        };

        header.showMenuBy(column.el.dom, column);
    }, this);

    this.headerCt.on('menucreate', function (header, column, event, html) {
        var menu = header.getMenu();

        this.createHeaderMenu(menu);
    }, this);
},

createHeaderMenu: function (menu) {
    menu.removeAll();

    // simulate header menu to be plain (menu is already created at this point)
    menu.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu-plain');
    menu.name = 'report_data_header_menu';

    menu.add({
        name: 'sort_asc',
        text: 'Sort Ascending'
    }, {
        name: 'sort_desc',
        text: 'Sort Descending'
    }, {
        name: 'remove_column',
        text: 'Remove'
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure you call "this.callParent(arguments)" before accessing "this.headerCt".
I have had problems because I was trying to access "this.headerCt" before calling "this.callParent(arguments)" and "this.headerCt" was undefined. Your example helped me to sort that problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it.

Add a listener on the 'menucreate' event on the Ext.grid.header.Container object. This delegate will pass you the reference of the menu then you can manipulate the Menu.

example

```
var gridHeader = gridPanelInstance.getView().headerCt; //return the Header Container 

gridHeader.on('menucreate', function(gridHeaderContainer, menu, option) {

    // do whatever you want with the menu here...  eg: add/remove/ edit menu item
});
```