# Extjs4: Customize dropdown menu in grid column header

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I wanted to customize the dropdown of each column header in a grid panel. The idea is to have a filter for each column (example:

Grades (dropdown menu shows checkbox with K,1,2,4 as a filter)
K
1
2
K
4

I found this solution to manipulate the dropdown menu, but problem it's that this alter all dropdown and not each one.

[Add a custom button in column header dropdown menus {EXTJS 4}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348581/add-a-custom-button-in-column-header-dropdown-menus-extjs-4)

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the Grid Filters feature ux. They add menu items into the header menu

Comment: Yes, filters are an option but I want then to be the only thing that displays when the dropdown is shown. I also want to display one filter per header. For example "Grades" => "1,2,k", "age" => 1,2,3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally end up using the "Grid Filters feature ux", something it's better to stick to the road setup by ext.