# Add custom item to grid menu in ExtJS3

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs3

I'm trying to make some changes on CMS, which uses ExtJs 3.
What I want is to add 2 buttons:

1. Show all posts
2. Show only my posts (there is a column called "Member")

I've founded the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348581/add-a-custom-button-in-column-header-dropdown-menus-extjs-4) , but it uses ExtJs 4 and is incompatible with older version. How can I do it for ExtJs 3?

Answer (score 0):

I know I don't give you enough information but I can suggest you to use a filter on the store to make the button works.

Something like:

```
MyStore.filter("Member", true);
```

And

```
MyStore.clearFilter();
```

I haven't create this kind of button (on the list of option) so I can't help for this part. Maybe you can create this button outside of the grid?

Hope this help